# Convert docker container exec command to docker-compose yml use

Tags: docker, docker-compose, exec

I want to execute a `docker container exec` command as part of my docker-compose.yml file. I want to avoid running a `docker container exec` command after I have run the docker-compose.yml file. Can anyone advise on how to do this please, by amending or updating the docker-compose.yml file?

The `docker conainter exec` command I want to avoid having to run is:

```
docker exec yacserver YACReaderLibraryServer add-library "My Comic Library" /comics
```

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  yacserver:
    container_name: yacserver
    image: xthursdayx/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest
    restart: unless-stopped

    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/London' # Put your own timezone here

    # We'll use host networking simply because it is way easier to setup.
    #network_mode: host
    
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
      - '/mnt/hgfs/Comics/yaclibrary:/comics:rw'
    
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

I have tried the following in troubleshooting my issue:

1. entering the container by `docker container exec -it yacserver sh` and running `YACReaderLibraryServer add-library "My Comic Library" /comics`. This does add the "My Comic Library" on the container and it verifies that sh exists as part of the container image.
2. creating alternative docker-compose.yml files based on the above with the command parameter, as the following `command: sh "YACReaderLibraryServer add-library 'Meerkat Comic Library' /comics"`

or

```
command: sh -c "YACReaderLibraryServer add-library 'My Comic Library' /comics"
```

or

```
command: sh -c 'YACReaderLibraryServer add-library "My Comic Library" /comics'
```

However none of these work to do add the My Comic Library into the container, all as part of the single docker-compose.yml file.

The following does not work as an example of a completed docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  yacserver:
    container_name: yacserver
    image: xthursdayx/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest
    restart: unless-stopped

    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/London' # Put your own timezone here

    # We'll use host networking simply because it is way easier to setup.
    #network_mode: host
    
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
      - '/mnt/hgfs/Comics/yaclibrary:/comics:rw'
    
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

    command: sh -c 'YACReaderLibraryServer add-library "My Comic Library" /comics'
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Does the command depend on the server running, or does it just touch local files?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully, or the nature of it, would you mind explaining please? 

The container modifies a library.ydb (Yacreader Database file) which is in the volume specified by the docker-compose.yml file.  

Do you mean does the container have to be brought up before the `docker container exec` command is issued?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a command to run after the container starts, but before the main container command runs, you can use an entrypoint wrapper script to do it.  If a Dockerfile has both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, then [the `CMD` is passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), and then if the `ENTRYPOINT` is a shell script, it can use the `exec "$@"` command to replace itself with the `CMD`.

For example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Load the externally-provided database
YACReaderLibraryServer add-library "My Comic Library" /comics

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, make sure to `COPY` this script in and set it as the `ENTRYPOINT`.  (If you had split `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` before – I see several SO questions that set `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]`, for example – combine both parts into a single `CMD`.)

```sh
# If a previous COPY command doesn't already include it
COPY entrypoint.sh .
# Must use JSON-array syntax
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
# Unchanged from before
CMD ./my_app
```

Note that this approach only works if your setup command(s) don't involve interacting with the running server.  Things like `cp`, `sed`, and `export` are great.  If your `add-library` command just involves copying a file, or if it's a self-contained program that directly invokes a local database system like SQLite, it's fine; if it makes an HTTP requests to the server, that will not work (and you'll get a "connection refused" error) because the server won't be running until the final `exec "$@"` step.

Comment: Sorry I realise I don't have all the appropriate knowledge or experience with Docker to respond fully. So I'll do the best I can. This image is downloaded so I do not have a Dockerfile that I created. So, with reference to your answer, how do I then modify a Dockerfile in the container? Or associated with the container? Do I create it myself? And then add reference to it in the docker-compose.yml file? 

Also, I just want the `docker container exec' command to be run after the container is up and running.

Comment: Can I ask how my docker-compose.yml file should be revised?

Comment: You could create a custom Dockerfile `FROM` the upstream image, but you need to know its `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` setup.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the `docker-compose.yml` file, except to change the `image:` line to `build: .` to use the local Dockerfile.  I'd also delete the unnecessary `container_name:` and the commented-out `network_mode: host` block.